# In Scarborough Fair, how is the length of a path defined?

Tags: scarborough-fair

The rules say that the customer always takes the shortest number of paths to the next stage.  It also says that the number of tents along the way is irrelevant.  Is path defined as a segment between tents, or is a path defined as a segment between stages?

Put another way, there's a couple places on the board that have paths between stages which have only one tent along the way.  Is the length of these segments one (stage-to-stage), or is the length two (stage-to-tent-to-stage)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two adjacent stages have a path length of one.  The designer has a [video playthrough](https://www.thegamecrafter.com/games/scarborough-fair) on the official website which makes this clear.  I was parsing things too closely and confused myself.